# How is it possible to implement read the image name by clicking on it

Tags: android, android-intent

Have a code that displays a random image:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int rndId = rand.nextInt(24) + 1;
imgName = "drw" + rndInt;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName()); 
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

How is it possible to implement read the image name by clicking on it in the program and create a new window with a description of the image that is unique to each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the Image Name if you have its resource id by using [`getResourceEntryName(resource_id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29),

```
String image_name = getResources().
                               getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Log.d("name", image_name);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ic_launcher
```